# Unable to manage presence roster smack, openfire

Tags: android, xmpp, smack, asmack

I m actually building an IM android app, using smack and openfire, but I have a problem.

In fact, I need to manage my roster presence. So, I use the code given by the smack tutorial :

```
leRoster.addRosterListener(new RosterListener() {

        public void entriesAdded(Collection<String> addresses) {
            for(String x : addresses)
            {
                Log.e("error listener",x);
            }
        }
        public void entriesDeleted(Collection<String> addresses) {}
        public void entriesUpdated(Collection<String> addresses) {

            for(String x : addresses)
            {
                Log.e("error listener",x);
            }

        }
        public void presenceChanged(Presence presence) {
            Log.e("error listener","Presence changed: " + presence.getFrom() + " " + presence);
        }
    });
```

I used Log.e (I love red color ...) to display information in the debugger.

My problem is : when a user of my roster is connecting, nothing appear in the log console. It means that I m not running that piece of code... 
I cant know if a new user is connected, or if a user changes his presence, and so I cant refresh my contact (roster) list on the screen.

Any idea ?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you set the subscription mode to manual?

leRoster.setSubscriptionMode(Roster.SubscriptionMode.manual);